# Is there a difference between these integral notations?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I've come across these two notations for calculating an indefinite integral but I'm not sure whether or not they are equal:

- $f(x)dx$
- $\int f(x)dx$

When calculating the indefinite integral, the first notation is used in my learning book, but isn't that the same as the second notation?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference where the notation appears?  The context might make it easier for people to explain the role of the notation.

Comment: ...the first is just a differential.

Comment: As J.M. says, if $\int f(x)dx = F(x)+C$, then $dF=f(x)dx$ is the differential.  At least, this is the usual notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is not an integral; it's a [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function). The second is an integral.

When doing substitution or integration by parts, one considers differentials. For example, to do integration by parts on
$$\int x\sin x\,dx$$
one can say "let $u=x$ and $dv = \sin x\,dx$." Then you want to find a function whose differential is $dv$, so  you are trying to find $\int dv = \int \sin x\,dx$; we usually don't actually write this, and simply write "then $v=-\cos x$", which may be what is confusing you and leading you to believe that "$\sin x\,dx$" is some kind of integral. But it's not an integral.

I'm just guessing, mind you, since you have not yet provided explicit examples of the use you believe refers to integrals.

Comment: This makes sense. It looks like I was overlooking something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first one usually denotes a [differential 1-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), where the second denotes the indefinite integral of $f$, i.e. it's anti-derivative.